# Eclipse and Classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, classpath

I swear I'm going insane.

JDeveloper runs my project with not a single complaint.

If I do "java -cp /usr/share/java/mysql.jar:. MAIN.java", it works like a charm.

But Eclipse says "[*censored*] you" and ignores my classpath settings.

I open the Run > Run... menu, and add the mysql jar in the classpath tab, but time and time again, I keep getting "No suitable driver found".

Now, I shouldn't have to add the jar to the build path ---otherwise, what's the point of using JDBC if I'm gonna rebuild if I wanna change the engine---. Nor should I have to do "`Class.forName()`", which I don't need in the other ways to run it.

A hand, in this insanity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just set your JRE to the proper Java6 one, instead of relying on Eclipse's autoconfig.

Yes, I'm talking to myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the jar as command line argument in Run dialog.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how I normally add jars to an eclipse project. Try following the steps in this [Wiki](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29).

Comment: Why whould I add it to the build path, if I'm not building MySQL into my app?

Comment: The build path is also used as the runtime classpath. You can alternatively add it in a launcher definition (and save that definition with the project if you want to share it -- see the "common" tab of the launcher config)