# Trouble running program in Eclipse - Classpath Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I dont know how to fix this problem. I am a new eclipse user. I really appreciate any help.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test_multiply/Matrix
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test_multiply.Matrix
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)


package test_multiply;
```

public class Matrix {

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    //taking value as command line argument.
    int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < num + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(i+"*"+j+"="+i * j);
            System.out.print("\t");         }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please tell us how you're trying to run your class, what it's actually called etc.

Comment: Please provide more inputs and try to post the code which causes this exception.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse and Classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819087/eclipse-and-classpath)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all the necessary jar files for your program.  The error is one dealing with Java, not eclipse, so eclipse should not have anything to do with the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

means, that the class which you are trying to run was not found in the classpath.So you can check if the class or .jar file is into appropriate java classpath.

Comment: package test_multiply;

public class Matrix {

 public static void main (String[] args) {
  //taking value as command line argument.
  int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

  for (int i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j < num + 1; j++) {
    System.out.print(i+"*"+j+"="+i * j);
    System.out.print("\t");
   }
   System.out.println();
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 0):

The error states that it can't find the `test_multiply.Matrix` class.  Additional projects and libraries can be added to your project's classpath be right-clicking on the project, selecting "Properties", and then navigating to "Java Build Path".